# SSH Tunneling on Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, ssh-tunnel, putty

I'd like to perform SSH tunneling on Windows. This is extremely trivial on Linux.

```
ssh -L 7456:someurl.com:7456 A.B.C.D:8080
```

This would cause SSH client to listen on 127.0.0.1:7456, and then connections on that port would be tunneled to the remote SSH server (A.B.C.D:8080) and then proxied to someurl.com:7456.

For some reason, I cannot find a similar way to accomplish this. Most people suggested putty, but the GUI makes no sense.

[Putty GUI Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffn3F.png)

What on earth do I put on the fields to accomplish the same result?

Comment: You would like to ssh to a Windows system?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the GUI to initiate a PuTTY connection. I actually prefer to just launch it from the Windows Run dialog or a powershell/cmd prompt most of the time.

The `Help` button in the screenshot you posted will open the PuTTY User Manual. In it, there's a whole section called `The PuTTY command line` within the section called `Using PuTTY`.  Specifically, section 3.8.3.5 is all about port forwarding.  From the manual:

> As well as setting up port forwardings in the PuTTY configuration (see section 4.25), you can also set up forwardings on the command line. The command-line options work just like the ones in Unix ssh programs.
>
> To forward a local port (say 5110) to a remote destination (say popserver.example.com port 110), you can write something like one of these:
>
> putty -L 5110:popserver.example.com:110 -load mysession
>
> plink mysession -L 5110:popserver.example.com:110
>
> To forward a remote port to a local destination, just use the -R option instead of -L:
>
> putty -R 5023:mytelnetserver.myhouse.org:23 -load mysession
>
> plink mysession -R 5023:mytelnetserver.myhouse.org:23

Based on your example, the command line would be something like this.

```
putty -L 7456:someurl.com:7456 -ssh A.B.C.D:8080
```

Also if you actually want to know how to use the GUI for setting up a tunnel, that's in section 4.25 called `The Tunnels panel`.